# Static Google Map image from "My Places" map?

Tags: google-maps-static-api

Im having a tough time finding out if I can simply snag an image from the places that I have marked in one of "my places" in google maps? Can I do this without typing all the code out that points to each individual location?

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The Google Maps API for static map images does **not support** viewing of a KML file – the file format you can export your *My Places* maps to.

If you want a map with **markers** and **locations** you have to either

- Supply all your markers in the request string using Googles Static Map API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/
- Use the dynamic JavaScript API, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial, and generate the map.

If you use the **interactive JavaScript** way you can load your KML file from your *My Places* maps by using this script:

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696, -87.624207);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 11,
  center: myLatLng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('[PATH_TO_KML]');
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

*As seen on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers*

in conjunction with the html example

```
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
```

*As seen on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial*

To get the KML, you open your map from your *My Places* and either

- copy the **provided KML link** (*I really don't understand when this shows and when it doesn't, someone could please clarify this in comments*), or
- copy the **link to the map** by pressing the link icon. Append `&output=kml` to the end of the link to get a link to the KML file.

*Note that loading a KML layer in the API automatically centers the view around the markers and selects a zoom level to encompass all markers.*